# Like pagination in AngularJS, If any plugins avail for nativescript angular 2[Both Android & Ios]

Tags: pagination, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to display the multiple results in listview. The total results may be hundreds of data's. I need to display in single page. I am new to this framework. I googled for this, but i got nativescript-pager plugin only as a suggestion.

Please suggest me with suitable solution.

My Nativescript environment -

Nativescript - 3.0.3
IDE - Visual studio code

Comment: Why not use a listview?

Comment: Thank you @mast3rd3mon . Yes. As you told listview is an one option. But i need to show first ten records in initial page. Likewise i need to split and show all the data's in followed screen. This is my requirement. For this how should i achieve using listview?